# How do you kick someone out of minecraft pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Someone has been grieving on my world and I was playing with my cousin so I didn't want to keep exiting or take off my wifi

Comment: Kicking generally refers to removing them from your server, but allowing them to come back. If someone's greifing then you probably want to Ban, rather than Kick.

Comment: [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117059/how-can-i-stop-people-from-joining-and-taking-stuff-in-survival-mode) might help against future grievers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing with Local server multiplayer then you cannot Blacklist users, however you can turn off the world, then once your cousin comes into the world turn off the Local Server Multiplayer option, this should keep your cousin in the world, but not allow any additional players.